# NLTK POS tagger not working

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, pos-tagger

If I try this :

```
import nltk
text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/pos.py", line 3, in <module>
nltk.pos_tag(text)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg\nltk\tag\__init__.py" ipos_tag
tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg\nltk\data.py", line 605,in 
resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))
ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the saved word tokenizer requires [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). You'll need to [install it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/).

Comment: If Numpy's required by NLTK, shouldn't it be installed as a dependency automatically assuming one used Pip or other installer tools?  I ask because I installed NLTK using Pip, then encountered the same issue.

Comment: @Inactivist Numpy's not required for most of NLTK, just some parts. (It's listed as optional on [the install page](http://nltk.org/install.html).) That said, it's super-handy to have around in general if you're doing any kind of machine learning type stuff or other number crunching.

Comment: wouldn't it be better for NLTK to split out the numpy-dependent code to a separate library

Answer (score 3):

Install numpy using the command:

```
sudo pip install -U numpy
```