# Error : No module named numpy.core.multiarray. Maxent tree bank pos-tagger model is already installed

Tags: numpy, pos-tagger

This is my program:

```
import nltk
text = "Rabbit is eating"
token2 = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
print token2
txttoken = nltk.pos_tag(token2)
print txttoken
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PosTag.py", line 8, in <module>

   txttoken = nltk.pos_tag(token2)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 99, in pos_tag
    tagger = load(_POS_TAGGER)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-2.0.4-py2.7.egg\nltk\data.py", line 605, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(_open(resource_url))

ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

I just check with `nltk.download()` on python cmd..

These models are already installed. But I still get the error..

NLTK Downloader Models. Maxent tree bank pos-tagger model is installed. punkt model is installed

Comment: Can you `import numpy`?

Comment: this question is answered here.... u just need to install numpy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506969/nltk-pos-tagger-not-working